# An error occurred creating the configuration section handler workerConfiguration - Start the project

Tags: c#

I am creating a Windows Application and when I try to create a custom section, I am getting the error below and I use this same code in a web project and it works normally.

```
ConfigurationErrorsException: An error occurred creating the configuration section handler for workerConfiguration: Could not load type 'ScumBot.Configuration.WorkerConfigurationSection' from assembly 'System.Configuration, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'. (C:\Repositorios\prisoner-bot\ScumBot\SumBot\bin\Debug\SumBot.exe.Config line 4)
```

WorkerConfigurationSection.cs

```
using System.Configuration;

namespace ScumBot.Configuration
{
  public class WorkerConfigurationSection : ConfigurationSection
  {
    [ConfigurationProperty("workers", IsDefaultCollection = false)]
    [ConfigurationCollection(typeof(WorkerConfigurationCollection), AddItemName = "add", ClearItemsName = "clear", RemoveItemName = "remove")]
    public WorkerConfigurationCollection Workers => (WorkerConfigurationCollection)base["workers"];
  }

  public class WorkerConfigurationCollection : ConfigurationElementCollection
  {
    public override ConfigurationElementCollectionType CollectionType => ConfigurationElementCollectionType.AddRemoveClearMap;

    protected override ConfigurationElement CreateNewElement() => new WorkerConfiguration();

    protected override object GetElementKey(ConfigurationElement element) => ((WorkerConfiguration)element).Name;

    public WorkerConfiguration this[int index]
    {
      get
      {
        return (WorkerConfiguration)BaseGet(index);
      }
      set
      {
        if (BaseGet(index) != null)
        {
          BaseRemoveAt(index);
        }

        BaseAdd(index, value);
      }
    }

    new public WorkerConfiguration this[string Name] => (WorkerConfiguration)BaseGet(Name);

    public int IndexOf(WorkerConfiguration service) => BaseIndexOf(service);

    public void Add(WorkerConfiguration service) => BaseAdd(service);

    protected override void BaseAdd(ConfigurationElement element) => BaseAdd(element, false);

    public void Remove(WorkerConfiguration service)
    {
      if (BaseIndexOf(service) >= default(int))
      {
        BaseRemove(service.Name);
      }
    }

    public void RemoveAt(int index) => BaseRemoveAt(index);

    public void Remove(string name) => BaseRemove(name);

    public void Clear() => BaseClear();
  }

  public class WorkerConfiguration : ConfigurationElement
  {
    public WorkerConfiguration()
    {
    }

    [ConfigurationProperty("name", DefaultValue = "ServiceName", IsRequired = true, IsKey = true)]
    public string Name
    {
      get
      {
        return (string)this["name"];
      }
      set
      {
        this["name"] = value;
      }
    }

    [ConfigurationProperty("autoStart", DefaultValue = false)]
    public bool AutoStart
    {
      get
      {
        return (bool)this["autoStart"];
      }
      set
      {
        this["autoStart"] = value;
      }
    }

    [ConfigurationProperty("actionWorkerCount", DefaultValue = 1)]
    [IntegerValidator(MinValue = 1, MaxValue = 1000, ExcludeRange = false)]
    public int ActionWorkerCount
    {
      get
      {
        return (int)this["actionWorkerCount"];
      }
      set
      {
        this["actionWorkerCount"] = value;
      }
    }

    [ConfigurationProperty("feedWorkerCount", DefaultValue = 1)]
    [IntegerValidator(MinValue = 1, MaxValue = 1000, ExcludeRange = false)]
    public int FeedWorkerCount
    {
      get
      {
        return (int)this["feedWorkerCount"];
      }
      set
      {
        this["feedWorkerCount"] = value;
      }
    }

    [ConfigurationProperty("workerInstances", DefaultValue = 1)]
    [IntegerValidator(MinValue = 1, MaxValue = 1000, ExcludeRange = false)]
    public int WorkerInstances
    {
      get
      {
        return (int)this["workerInstances"];
      }
      set
      {
        this["workerInstances"] = value;
      }
    }

    [ConfigurationProperty("lotSize", DefaultValue = 500)]
    [IntegerValidator(MinValue = 1, MaxValue = int.MaxValue, ExcludeRange = false)]
    public int LotSize
    {
      get
      {
        return (int)this["lotSize"];
      }
      set
      {
        this["lotSize"] = value;
      }
    }

    [ConfigurationProperty("sleepTimeInSeconds", DefaultValue = default(int))]
    [IntegerValidator(MinValue = default(int), MaxValue = int.MaxValue, ExcludeRange = false)]
    public int SleepTimeInSeconds
    {
      get
      {
        return (int)this["sleepTimeInSeconds"];
      }
      set
      {
        this["sleepTimeInSeconds"] = value;
      }
    }

    [ConfigurationProperty("noItemsSleepTimeInSeconds", DefaultValue = default(int))]
    [IntegerValidator(MinValue = default(int), MaxValue = int.MaxValue, ExcludeRange = false)]
    public int NoItemsSleepTimeInSeconds
    {
      get
      {
        return (int)this["noItemsSleepTimeInSeconds"];
      }
      set
      {
        this["noItemsSleepTimeInSeconds"] = value;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

App.Config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section type="ScumBot.Configuration.WorkerConfigurationSection" name="workerConfiguration" />
  </configSections>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2" />
  </startup>
  <workerConfiguration>
    <workers>
      <add name="ExecuteCommandWorker" autoStart="false" workerInstances="1" actionWorkerCount="1" sleepTimeInSeconds="20" />
      <add name="GetOrderWorker" autoStart="false" workerInstances="1" actionWorkerCount="2" sleepTimeInSeconds="20" />
    </workers>
  </workerConfiguration>
</configuration>
```

I tried to recreate the project and check if I did something wrong, but whenever I create a windows application it doesn't work and in a web project it works normally. I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: `<section type="ScumBot.Configuration.WorkerConfigurationSection"` should be `<section type="ScumBot.Configuration.WorkerConfigurationSection, ScumBot"`

Comment: I tried it but it didn't work.